# ゲーム数学3D ベクトルｘスカラーをどのように計算するのか知りたい。関数の作り方で困ってます。

Tags: c++

DxLib3D(DirectX)です。.cpp部のクォータニオン掛け算部の関数のreturn文のPositin::mul();部の関数を定義したいのですが引数にスカラー、ベクトルを入れてその計算をさせたいのですがタイトル通り**スカラーｘベクトルの計算式**がわかりません　ゲーム数学でしょうか？　3次元です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
mainループでキー入力で使う予定の関数

```
/*X軸回転*/
void rotate_X(float *x,float *y,float *z,const float ang, const float mx,const float my,const float mz)
{

    Quaternion P(0,Position(*x - mx, *y - my, *z - mz));//回転させる点
    Position v(1,0,0);//回転させる軸

    Quaternion Q(cos(ang / 2), Position(v.x * sin(ang / 2), v.y * sin(ang / 2), v.z * sin(ang / 2)));
    Quaternion R(cos(ang / 2), Position(-v.x * sin(ang / 2) , -v.y * sin(ang / 2), -v.z * sin(ang / 2)));

    Quaternion result = R * Q * P;

}
```

Position.hpp部

```
#ifndef ___POSITION_H
#define ___POSITION_H

//template<typename type>
class Quaternion
{
public:

    /*実部*/
    float a;

    /*虚部*/
//  Position<type> v;
    Position v;

    Quaternion(float aa, Position vv);

    static Quaternion mul(Quaternion a, Quaternion b);//掛け算



};



//template<typename type>
class Position
{
private:




public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    Position(float xx, float yy, float zz);
    Position();




    static Position cross(Position a, Position b);//外積
    static float dot(Position a,Position b);//内積








};

#endif
```

Position.cpp部

```
/*クォータニオン*/

Quaternion::Quaternion(float aa,Position vv)
{
    a = aa;

    v.x = vv.x;
    v.y = vv.y;
    v.z = vv.z;
}

/*クォータニオンの掛け算部　　　　　　Position::mul()は実装してませんよってコンパイルエラー　*/
Quaternion Quaternion::mul(Quaternion a, Quaternion b)
{
    return Quaternion(a.a + b.a - (Position::dot(a.v,b.v)),Position(Position::mul(a.a , b.v) + Position::mul(b.a , a.v) + Position::cross(a.v,b.v)));
}

/*外積*/
Position Position::cross(Position a,Position b)
{
    return Position(a.y * b.y - b.y * a.z,
                            (-1) * (a.x * b.z - b.x * a.z),
                                a.x * b.y  - b.x * a.y);
}

/*内積*/
float Position::dot(Position a, Position b)
{
    return (a.x * b.x) + (a.y * b.y) + (a.z * a.z);
}

/*座標系*/

//template<typename type>
Position::Position(float xx,float yy,float zz)
{
    x = xx;
    y = yy;
    z = zz;
}



//template<typename type>
Position::Position()
{
    x = 0.0f;
    y = 0.0f;
    z = 0.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ベクトルのスカラー倍は要素ごとにそのスカラー倍したものです。

**v** = (x, y) として、
2・**v** = v + v = (x + x, y + y) = (2・x, 2・y)
k・**v** = (k・x, k・y)